# Find the largest sum of the GCD and LCM of two numbers in a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded

The program is supposed to get one number *n* as input, and output the max value of gcd + lcm of two numbers that range from 1 to *n*.

For example, if n == 3, the answer is 7 because gcd(3,2) == 1 and lcm(3,2) == 6.

The issue is that the code works really slowly and the double loop makes it so numbers above basically 1000 take forever to run. How do I make it run faster?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    cin >> n;

    int highest_value = 0,equation;
    int gcd,smaller;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if(i > j){smaller=j;}
            else{smaller=i;}

            for(int y = 1; y <= smaller; y++)
            {
                if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
            }
            equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd);
                if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
        }
    }
    cout << highest_value;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! This was migrated from SO, but please take the [tour] and see [ask]. It'd be helpful if you'd use the explanation you used on SO, namely, that the code isn't performant enough. Otherwise, this just feels like a code dump. Thanks for clarifying and explaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to take a stab at this, and I ended up reducing your algorithm down to one line (tested for equality with the original algorithm from n = [0,500] :

```
highest_value = (n > 2) ? ( 1+n*(n-1) ) : ( 2*n );
```

If you would like to see the steps I took, then please see my steps below...

Let's start by removing the comparison in the 2nd loop by splitting up the 2nd loop into 2 parts:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // smaller = j
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= j/*smaller*/; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd); //since lcm(x,y) = (x*y)/gcd(x,y)
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    }
    // smaller = i
    for(int j = i; j <= n; j++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= i/*smaller*/; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd); //since lcm(x,y) = (x*y)/gcd(x,y)
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    }
}
```

Now let's extract the simple case where `i == j` by adding

```
// i == j
// gcd = i;
// equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd);
// equation = i + (i*i)/i
equation = 2 * i;
if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
```

and changing the limits of the second loop to exclude `i == j`

```
for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
```

we now have

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // i == j
    equation = 2 * i;
    if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    // smaller = j
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= j/*smaller*/; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd); //since lcm(x,y) = (x*y)/gcd(x,y)
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    }
    // smaller = i
    for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= i/*smaller*/; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd); //since lcm(x,y) = (x*y)/gcd(x,y)
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    }
}
```

we can observe that the second loop checks the same values (just mirrored with i and j), so we can get rid of the second loop entirely giving us:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // i == j
    equation = 2 * i;
    if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    // smaller = j
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= j/*smaller*/; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd); //since lcm(x,y) = (x*y)/gcd(x,y)
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    }
}
```

we can also observe that the maximum value for the i == j case will be where `i == n`, so we can get rid of that section and start our highest_value at 2*n :

```
int highest_value = 2*n;
int equation, gcd;

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // smaller = j
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        for(int y = 1; y <= j; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd); //since lcm(x,y) = (x*y)/gcd(x,y)
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
    }
}

return highest_value;
```

Now let's look at the inner-most loop

```
for(int y = 1; y <= j; y++) {
    if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
}
```

we know that y == 1 is a simple case where `gcd = 1` and `equation = 1 + i*j`, so we can extract that from the loop:

```
equation = 1 + i*j;
if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;

for(int y = 2; y <= j; y++) {
    if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
}
```

let's also notice that the equation `1 + i*j` has a maximum consistent with the maximum values of i and j where `i = n` and `j = n-1` which gives us `1 + n*(n-1)` or `1 + n*n - n`. Now we can move this equation to the beginning of the function and check it against our initial highest_value of `2 * n`. Don't forget to exclude the case where `n == 0`, because it is impossible to achieve a value of `i` or `j == 0` inside the loop.

```
int highest_value = 2*n;
int gcd, equation;

if ( n > 0 ) {
    equation = 1 + n*(n-1);
    if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;
}
```

We can notice that our new equation exceed our initial equation at a value of `n >= 3`

```
int highest_value, gcd, equation;

if ( n > 2 ) {
    highest_value = 1 + n*(n-1);
} else {
    highest_value = 2 * n;
}
```

We can notice that `i == 1` and `j == 1` will never be divisible by the initial value of `y`, so we can start them at 2. Then notice that the j loop never happens if `i == 2`, so we can start i at 3.

```
int highest_value, gcd, equation;

if ( n > 2 ) {
    highest_value = 1 + n*(n-1);
} else {
    highest_value = 2 * n;
}

for(int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
    for(int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        for(int y = 2; y <= j; y++) {
            if(i%y==0 && j%y==0) gcd = y;
        }
        equation = gcd+((i*j)/gcd);
        if(equation > highest_value) highest_value = equation;

    }
}

return highest_value;
```

Finally... We can notice a pattern where we can take this approach indefinitely where we can continue to factor our i and j, so I noticed a pattern where the initial highest_value is true for every i and j, so the final function is :

```
highest_value = (n > 2) ? ( 1+n*(n-1) ) : ( 2*n );
```